# Paging 3 only display data when open fragment for the second time

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging-3

I'm having an issue using Paging 3 library. I'm using retrofit to get data and paging 3 to display it but what is happening right now is that when I open my fragment for the first time, nothing is displayed on the fragment but when I close this fragment and open it again, data is displayed. What is happening?

I navigate from one fragment to another using Navigation. I'm using Koin in this project if this could help to find a solution.

**My code:**

**Service:**

```
interface APICalls{
    @GET(MYAPIURL)
    suspend fun getData(
        @Header("Auth") auth : String,
        @Query("pageSize") pageSize:Int
    ):Response<ResponseData>
}
```

**Models:**

```
data class ResponseData(
    @SerializedName("listData") val listData:MutableList<DataAPI>,
    @SerializedName("pageSize") val pageSize : Int
):Serializable

data class DataAPI(
    @SerializedName("id") val id:Int,
    @SerializedName("data")val data: String
): Serializable
```

**Result wrapper:**

```
class Result<out T:Any>{
    data class Success<T:Any>(val value: T): Result<T>()
    data class Failure(val message:String, val errorCode:Int?):Result<Nothing>()
}
```

**PagingSource:**

```
val responseData = mutableListOf<DataAPI>()
class DataAPIPagingSource(private val token:String,private val apiCalls:APICalls) : PagingSource<Int,DataAPI>{
    
    override fun getRefreshKey(...):Int?{
        return null
    }
    override suspend fun load(params : LoadParams<Int>):LoadResult<Int,DataAPI>{
        return try{
            val currentPage = params.key ?: 1
            val response = apiCalls.getData(token)
            response.body()?.let{
                Result.Success(it)  
            }?: run{
                Result.Failure(response.message(),response.code())
            }
            val data = response.body()?.listData ?: emptyList()
            responseData.addAll(data)
            LoadResult.Page(responseData,if(currentPage ==1) null else -1),currentPage.plus(1)
            

        }catch(e:Exception){
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }   
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class DataViewModel(private val apiCalls:APICalls): ViewModel {

    //I get this token in shared preference
    val token = .....

    val mydata = getDataList()
        .map{pagingData -> pagingData.map{DataModel.DataItem(it)}}

    private fun getDataList(){
        return Pager(PagingConfig(25)){
            DataAPIPagingSource(token,apiCalls)
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}

sealed class DataModel{
    data class DataItem(val dataitem: DataAPI) : DataModel()
}

private val DataModel.DataItem.identificator : Int
    get() = this.dataItem.id
```

**Fragment:**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(){
    private val myAdapter : DataAdapter by lazy{
        DataAdapter()
    }
    private val viewModelFactory : ViewModelFactory by inject()
    private val dataViewModel : DataViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_graph){viewModelFactory}


    override fun onViewCreated(...){
        super.onViewCreated(...)
        binding.myRecyclerView.apply{
            adapter = myAdapter
            layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
        }
        
        lyfecycleScope.launch{
            dataViewModel.mydata.collect{myAdapter.submitData(it)}
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class DataAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<DataModel,RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DataModelComparator){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position:Int){

        val dataModel : DataModel? = getItem(position)
        dataModel.let{
            when(dataModel){
                is DataModel.DataItem ->{
                    val viewHolder = holder as DataItemViewHolder
                    viewHolder.binding.textview1.text = dataModel.dataitem.data
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override fun getItemViewType(position:Int):Int{
        return when(getItem(position)){
            is DataModel.DataItem -> R.layout.item_data
            null -> throw UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown view")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(...){
        return when(viewType){
            R.layout.item_data ->{
                DataItemViewHolder(ItemDataBinding.inflate(...))
            }
        }
    }
    
    class DataItemViewHolder(val binding: DataItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    companion object {
         val DataModelComparator = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataModel>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
                 return oldItem.dataitem.id == newItem.dataitem.id
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataModel, newItem: DataModel): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often get your problem when I use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView.
Just set up size for layout_height.

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/yourRecyclerView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="970dp"
   android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```